# Xamarin.Forms Picker Selection BackgroundColor

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, material-design-in-xaml

I am Searching for a proper fix on how to change the Color of the Pickers (Date & Time) in Xamarin Forms. I already have the Custom Renderer to customize the Dialog, but is there also a similar possibility to customize the Background Color of the displayed Picker itself(and the annoying Pink line) on all Instances at once?
I found out how to make it, but my solution is not that elegant since i have to define the Background Color on each Instance throughout the App.
[image: i want the Blue Box behind the 16:00 to disappear]

-> i want the Blue Box behind the 16:00 to disappear

the code to the picture i have as follows:

```
               <TimePicker Grid.Row="5"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            x:Name="BtnTime2"
                            Format="t"/>

                <Button Grid.Row="5"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        x:Name="BtnTime2Now"
                        CornerRadius="15"/>

                <DatePicker Grid.Row="6"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            x:Name="BtnDate"
                            Format="D"
                            BackgroundColor="#00000000"/>
```

Hope anybody of you guys can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok nevermind...
i already had the solution in my App.xaml

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Arbeitszeitrechner_Forms.App">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        
        ...some more Styles here...

        <Style TargetType="TimePicker">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#00000000"/>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Text}"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="DatePicker">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#00000000"/>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Text}"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```